# PHP Imagick - "Memory allocation failed" for PSD

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Everything is working perfectly except when I use a PSD, then I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Memory allocation failed `/tmp/phptfUzsA' @ psd.c/ReadPSDImage/1035' in /var/www/html/lib/ext/s98lib/classes/image.php:74
```

My current memory limit is at **128mb**. I tried increasing it to 256mb with no luck.

Further research shows that it gives this problem when it has other issues with the file. Seeing as how JPGs and PNGs work just fine, it seems specifically to be wrong with PSDs.

This is the code I am using:

```
/**
 * Resize to PNG
 *
 * @throws InvalidParametersException
 *
 * @param string $image_path
 * @param int $width
 * @param int $height
 * @return string
 */
public static function resize_to_png( $image_path, $width, $height ) {
    if ( !file_exists( $image_path ) )
        throw new InvalidParametersException( 'No file exists to resize' );

    $info = getimagesize( $image_path );

    if ( empty( $info ) )
        throw new InvalidParametersException( 'No image information exists in file' );

    // Get data
    $mime = $info['mime'];

    // What sort of image?
    $type = substr( strrchr( $mime, '/' ), 1 );

    // Start doing stuff
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    $image->readimage( $image_path );

    if ( 'psd' == $type )
        $image->setIteratorIndex(0);

    // Create thumbnail
    $image->thumbnailImage( $width, $height, false, true );

    $tmp_file = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'gcitem_' );

    $image->writeImage( 'png:' . $tmp_file );

    return $tmp_file;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: PSD is quite a complex format, and closed source I assume, so you probably won't be able to open all the PSD files.

Comment: As far as I understand, Imagick is supposed to be able to handle it.